# How to make Django Dynamic Inline Forms as like admin (using Class Based Views)?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

I have 2 Models

```
class Section(models.Model):
    SECTION_CHOICES_CLASS_6_7_8 = [
        ("A", "Section A"),
        ("B", "Section B"),
        ("C", "Section C"),
    ]

    SECTION_CHOICES_CLASS_9_10 = [
        ("Sc", "Science"),
        ("Co", "Commerce"),
        ("Ar", "Arts"),
    ]

    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        verbose_name="Section",
        choices=SECTION_CHOICES_CLASS_6_7_8 + SECTION_CHOICES_CLASS_9_10,
    )
    description = models.TextField(
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        help_text="Section Description, e.g. 'Section A of Class 6, total 30 students'",
    )
    class_name = models.ForeignKey(
        Class,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        help_text="Class",
        verbose_name="Class",
    )

    teacher = models.OneToOneField(
        "Teacher",
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        verbose_name="Section Teacher",
    )
    seat = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    subjects = models.ManyToManyField(Subject, through="SectionSubject")
```

```
class SectionSubject(models.Model):
    section = models.ForeignKey(Section, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    teachers = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    period = models.IntegerField(
        default=0, validators=[MaxValueValidator(10), MinValueValidator(0)]
    )
    time = models.TimeField(
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
```

After configuring the admin, Using Tabular Inline

[image: admin view]

How can I achieve the same kinda UI functionality in the template.

Or suggest me a better way to make it comfortable for user.

I've tried the `inlineformset_factory`

> forms.py

```
class SectionSubjectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SectionSubject
        fields = "__all__"

        widgets = {
            "subject": forms.Select(attrs={"class": "form-select"}),
            "teachers": forms.Select(attrs={"class": "form-select"}),
            "period": forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control "}),
            "time": forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control "}),
        }


SectionSubjectInlineFormset = inlineformset_factory(
    Section,
    SectionSubject,
    form=SectionSubjectForm,
    extra=1,
    can_delete=True,
    can_delete_extra=True,
)
```

> views.py

```
class SectionCreateView(SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    form_class = SectionForm
    template_name = "dashboard/section/section_add_or_update.html"
    success_message = "Section created successfully"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            context["section_subjects"] = SectionSubjectInlineFormset(self.request.POST)
        else:
            context["section_subjects"] = SectionSubjectInlineFormset()
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        subjects = context["section_subjects"]
        with transaction.atomic():
            self.object = form.save()

            if subjects.is_valid():
                subjects.instance = self.object
                subjects.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy("dashboard:section_detail", kwargs={"pk": self.object.pk})


class SectionUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Section
    form_class = SectionForm
    template_name = "dashboard/section/section_add_or_update.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            context["section_subjects"] = SectionSubjectInlineFormset(self.request.POST)
        else:
            context["section_subjects"] = SectionSubjectInlineFormset()
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        subjects = context["section_subjects"]
        with transaction.atomic():
            self.object = form.save()

            if subjects.is_valid():
                subjects.instance = self.object
                subjects.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy("dashboard:section_detail", kwargs={"pk": self.object.pk})
```

> dashboard/section/section_add_or_update.html

```
{% extends "dashboard/dashboard.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Assign Section</h1>

<!-- Include jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}

    <div id="subject-form">
        {{ section_subjects.management_form }}
        <div id="empty-form" style="display: none;">
            {{ section_subjects.empty_form }}
        </div>

        <h2>Subjects</h2>
        <div class="subjects-container">
            {% for form in section_subjects %}
            <div class="subject-form-row">
                {{ form.as_p }}
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove-subject">Remove</button>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>

    <button id="add-subject" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Add Subject</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Save</button>
</form>

<style>
    /* Add CSS styles for better visual representation */
    .subject-form-row {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
</style>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#add-subject').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            const formCount = $('#id_subject_set-TOTAL_FORMS').val();
            const newForm = $('#empty-form').html().replace(/__prefix__/g, formCount);
            $('.subjects-container').append(newForm);
            $('#id_subject_set-TOTAL_FORMS').val(parseInt(formCount) + 1);
        });

        $(document).on('click', '.remove-subject', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).closest('.subject-form-row').remove();
            const formCount = $('#id_subject_set-TOTAL_FORMS').val();
            $('#id_subject_set-TOTAL_FORMS').val(parseInt(formCount) - 1);
        });
    });
</script>
{% endblock content %}
```

1. While I'm Creating a Section If I add multiple subject then It only saving the first item
2. Update - Same result

I'm trying to make a view same as the admin view.